# asp:Literal strips out title attribute value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-literal

I am working on a asp.net website (web forms and mvc) where asp:Literal is used in a few pages.
I needed to change the content of one page to add a simple title attribute to the existing  tag.

So i need the rendered result to be:

```
<a href="test.jpg" 
   title="title here" 
   id="testimage" 
   rel="hint-text: CLICK TO ZOOM" 
   style="position: relative; display: inline-block">image goes here</a>
```

But after rendering, it looks like that:

```
<a href="test.jpg" 
   title id="testimage" 
   rel="hint-text: CLICK TO ZOOM" 
   style="position: relative; display: inline-block">image goes here</a>
```

At first i thought it could be something to do with the controls Mode property, but even if i change the Mode to PassThrough it still does not render the value of the tittle attribute.

EDIT: The code for the literal is as folows:

```
LiteralControl.Text = "<a href='test.jpg' title='title here' id='testimage' rel='hint-text: CLICK TO ZOOM' style='position: relative; display: inline-block'>image goes here</a>"
```

Does any of you guys have this problem and happens to know the solution?

Comment: Are you checking directly in html source ? Some browser dev browser plugins can "eat up" title attribute content.

Comment: What's the actual code for the literal?

Comment: @Ademar Your code is fine; it renders as `<a href='test.jpg' title='title here' ...` in Chrome, IE and FF.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar, Man you are my hero today! it seems like its a problem with chrome dev plugin as when i check the source its there (as you suggested).